# centos 6.4: apache not loading xdebug. Says undefined symbol: sapi_globals

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, centos6

I am using centos 6.4

```
[root@storm]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

I have installed xdebug using the command (only showing the partial output)

```
[root@storm]# pecl install Xdebug
Failed loading xdebug.so:  xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
downloading xdebug-2.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.3.2.tgz (266,287 bytes)
........................................................done: 266,287 bytes
74 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootNTtRn6/xdebug-2.3.2
.
.
.
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-2.3.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so" to php.ini
```

The following is my /etc/php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

after i do

```
[root@storm]# service httpd restart
```

I see the following lines added in the /var/log/httpd/error.log

```
[Fri Jul 24 13:21:12 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: sapi_globals
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: sapi_globals
[Fri Jul 24 13:21:14 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jul 24 13:21:14 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jul 24 13:21:14 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Jul 24 13:21:14 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.43 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

which shows xdebug in not loaded.

The following is the php details

```
[root@storm]# php -v
PHP 5.4.43 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2015 12:08:50) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

I have test.php with

```
<?php

phpinfo();
?>
```

when i open http://localhost/test.php in browser the following is the output. (it does not show xdebug as loaded because of which i got the doubt and saw the output of /var/log/httpd/error.log)

```
PHP Logo
PHP Version 5.4.43

System  Linux storm.temple 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 12 03:34:52 UTC 2013 x86_64
Build Date  Jul 8 2015 12:10:43
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php-zts.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php-zts.d/curl.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/dom.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/gd.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/gmp.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/imap.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/json.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/mcrypt.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/opcache.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/phar.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/posix.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/soap.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/sqlite3.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/sysvsem.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/sysvshm.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/wddx.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/xhprof.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/xmlrpc.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/xsl.ini, /etc/php-zts.d/zip.ini
PHP API     20100412
PHP Extension   20100525
Zend Extension  220100525
Zend Extension Build    API220100525,TS
PHP Extension Build     API20100525,TS
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*

Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

PHP Credits
Configuration
apache2handler
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.24 (CentOS)
Apache API Version  20051115
Server Administrator    webservants.rns@gmail.com
Hostname:Port   radhanathswamiinspires.com:0
User/Group  apache(48)/48
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 120 - Keep-Alive: 15
Virtual Server  Yes
Server Root     /etc/httpd
Loaded Modules  core worker http_core mod_so mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_file_cache mod_mem_cache mod_cgi mod_dnssd mod_php5 mod_proxy_ajp

Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0

Apache Environment
Variable    Value
HTTP_HOST   radhanathswamiinspires.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT     Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
HTTP_ACCEPT     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-US,en;q=0.5
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION     keep-alive
PATH    /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE    no value
SERVER_SOFTWARE     Apache/2.2.24 (CentOS)
SERVER_NAME     radhanathswamiinspires.com
SERVER_ADDR     192.168.1.22
SERVER_PORT     80
REMOTE_ADDR     192.168.4.160
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/sites/lwsites/inspires/public_html
SERVER_ADMIN    webservants.rns@gmail.com
SCRIPT_FILENAME     /home/sites/lwsites/inspires/public_html/sample.php
REMOTE_PORT     58897
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI     /sample.php
SCRIPT_NAME     /sample.php

HTTP Headers Information
HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /sample.php HTTP/1.1
Host    radhanathswamiinspires.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
HTTP Response Headers
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.43

bz2
BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.5, 10-Dec-2007

calendar
Calendar support    enabled

Core
PHP Version     5.4.43

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  Off Off
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 32767   32767
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules  /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php    .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision 17  17
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 20M 20M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value

ctype
ctype functions     enabled

curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.19.7
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN     Yes
IPv6    Yes
Largefile   Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL     Yes
SSPI    No
krb4    No
libz    Yes
CharConv    No
Protocols   tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps, scp, sftp
Host    x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version     NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC
ZLib Version    1.2.3
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.2

date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    UTC

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   Asia/Kolkatta   Asia/Kolkatta

dom
DOM/XML     enabled
DOM/XML API Version     20031129
libxml Version  2.7.6
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support     enabled

ereg
Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

exif
EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: 7f95ff43ea7cc9a2c41a912863ed70069c0e34c5 $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes     JPEG,TIFF

Directive   Local Value Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel   JIS JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola    JIS JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel   UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    UCS-2BE UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis no value    no value
exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15

fileinfo
fileinfo support    enabled
version     1.0.5

filter
Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: ad78b4a085153b8c7f4d6db5dc69df40e969c343 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp
FTP support     enabled

gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.11
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version     6b
PNG Support     enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.49
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support     enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0

gettext
GetText Support     enabled

gmp
gmp support     enabled
GMP version     4.3.1

hash
hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.12

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

imap
IMAP c-Client Version   2007e
SSL Support     enabled
Kerberos Support    enabled

json
json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version     2.7.6
libXML Loaded Version   20706
libXML streams  enabled

mbstring
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine     libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation     disabled
libmbfl version     1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check     On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version     4.7.1

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input pass    pass
mbstring.http_output    pass    pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value

mcrypt
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version     2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mhash
MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support

mysql
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.5.39
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient_r

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off

mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.5.39
Active Persistent Links     0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.5.44
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off

openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.37 2015-04-28

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.5.39

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.6.20

Phar
Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.1
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: ba734629367f9671b25202408d13914fa63d8396 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives     enabled
ZIP-based phar archives     enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
Native OpenSSL support  enabled

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

posix
Revision    $Id: 1dfa9997ed76804e53c91e0ce862f3707617b6ed $

Reflection
Reflection  enabled
Version     $Id: f6367cdb4e3f392af4a6d441a6641de87c2e50c4 $

session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

shmop
shmop support   enabled

SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: 16070fc92ad6f69cebb2d52ad3f02794f833ce39 $
Schema support  enabled

soap
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400

sockets
Sockets Support     enabled

SPL
SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes     AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

sqlite3
SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite3 module version  0.7
SQLite Library  3.6.20

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir   no value    no value

standard
Dynamic Library Support     enabled
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value

sysvmsg
sysvmsg support     enabled
Revision    $Id: adf1d2d6be849c46eed3c3ee6f1cbebd1448d6e5 $

tokenizer
Tokenizer Support   enabled

wddx
WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer     enabled

xhprof
xhprof  0.9.2
CPU num 1

xml
XML Support     active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version     2.7.6

xmlreader
XMLReader   enabled

xmlrpc
core library version    xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
php extension version   0.51
author  Dan Libby
homepage    http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by     Epinions.com

xmlwriter
XMLWriter   enabled

xsl
XSL     enabled
libxslt Version     1.1.26
libxslt compiled against libxml Version     2.7.6
EXSLT   enabled
libexslt Version    1.1.26

Zend OPcache
Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
Startup     OK
Shared memory model     mmap
Cache hits  1827
Cache misses    364
Used memory     32120304
Free memory     102097424
Wasted memory   0
Cached scripts  364
Cached keys     467
Max keys    7963
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts  0
Manual restarts     0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename  /etc/php-zts.d/opcache*.blacklist   /etc/php-zts.d/opcache*.blacklist
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   no value    no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0   0
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 8   8
opcache.load_comments   1   1
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   4000    4000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  128 128
opcache.optimization_level  0xFFFFFFFF  0xFFFFFFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On

zip
Zip     enabled
Extension Version   $Id: abc21c7f1559e732dba6db94c69ecf638ae5fa3f $
Zip version     1.11.0
Libzip version  0.10.1

zlib
ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.3
Linked Version  1.2.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value

Additional Modules
Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm

Environment
Variable    Value
TERM    xterm
PATH    /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
PWD     /
LANG    C
SHLVL   2
_   /usr/sbin/httpd.worker

PHP Variables
Variable    Value
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    radhanathswamiinspires.com
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-US,en;q=0.5
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["PATH"] /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] no value
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.2.24 (CentOS)
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  radhanathswamiinspires.com
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  192.168.1.22
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  192.168.4.160
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /home/sites/lwsites/inspires/public_html
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] webservants.rns@gmail.com
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /home/sites/lwsites/inspires/public_html/sample.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  58897
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /sample.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /sample.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /sample.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]   1437724624.872
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1437724624

PHP License

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group and included in the distribution in the file: LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xdebug.so library is linked incorrectly. Try to link the shared library manually or download a version that matches your OS (including your kernel version) and your version of apache. Also this is a known bug in some versions of apache/php (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=17147): try to update your version of apache.

Answer (score 0):

You try

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
...
```

If there are problems, then try to rewrite the compiler installation

Comment: its not a problem of xdebug configuration. I am looking for a solution for undefined symbol: sapi_globals